# UWP ProgressBar IsIndeterminate false avoid animation

Tags: c#, animation, uwp

I'm currently developping a UWP app with a simple page containing a progressBar. 
the IsIndeterminate value is bound to a property IsLoading. 
When the property value is true, Isindeterminate=true and the animation works perfectly.

the problem occurs when the value becomes false. Another animation starts; points go back to the left of the progressBar which is unclean.

Is it possible to simple avoid this animation to be played ? 
by advance thank you.

Régis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`IsIndeterminate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressbar.isindeterminate) property you set false will appear the animation you described due to uncertainty. And it is by design, From your scenario, you can use [`ShowPaused`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressbar.showpaused) property to control whether the progress bar is paused.

Comment: Perfect !! the following line describe my xaml control. thanks a lot for your quick answer.
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsLoading}" ShowPaused="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BoolNegationConverter}}" Background="Transparent" />